# extjs displaying loadmask on panel when store loads

Tags: javascript, extjs

I added a loadmask to a panel and I want the spinner to be displayed each time stores associated with the loadmask are loaded. The panel is a large tooltip and the stores are loaded each time a point is visited in a line chart. Thus, when I hover over a point, I'm expecting a load message to appear for a short period of time before I see the contents in the panel. What I'm getting is an empty panel however. If I remove the code that I have which adds the load mask (the initComponent function), it works (without the load message though). How would I use the loadmask in this manner as opposed to explicitly calling the setLoading() method for each panel?

Here's the code:

```
tips:
{
  ...
  items:{
    xtype: 'panel',
    initComponent: function(){
      var loadMask = new Ext.LoadMask(this, {
        store: Ext.getStore('CompanyContext')
      });
    },
    id: 'bar-tip-panel',
    width: 700,
    height: 700,
    layout: {
      type: 'accordion',
      align : 'stretch',
      padding: '5 5 5 5'
    },
    items:... 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config` object isn't the proper place to override `initComponent` method. What you should do is to define a subclass of `Panel`, and override the method there.

```
Ext.define('MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'mypanel',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments); // MUST call parent's method

        var loadMask = new Ext.LoadMask(this, {
            store: ...
        });
    },
});
```

Then, you can use xtype `mypanel` in your `tips` configuration.